# How to check if the result of DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) is exist in a column?

Tags: mysql

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column CONTAIN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())"
```

The DateType of the column is VARCHAR and the data is number with comma like "0,1,2,4,5"

Example today is Friday DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) will return 6 how can I check if the column contain 6?

Comment: You really should normalize your table schema so you don't have a comma-separated list in the first place. But see the linked question for how to use `FIND_IN_SET()` to do what you want.

Comment: @Barmar thanks this work for me FIND_IN_SET(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()),column)>0

Comment: select * from test where testcolumn like Concat('%',DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()),'%') would work too